# Remove the flag counter from admin panel if there're no flags

Tags: feature-request, design, flags, moderator-tools

On the site admin panel there's a flag count icon displayed as a part of "flags" tab:

> [image: Moderator's admin panel, showing flag tab with an orange "0"]

Could we please remove that icon in the case there're no active flags? i.e. don't show an orange "0" icon, to prevent mod distraction.

This will work in a same manner the number of unprocessed flags from the top bar next to the diamond icon.

A similar design is used on "Bountied" tab, if there're no questions with bounty — then there is no icon at all:

> [image: Bounty tab, showing the number of active bounties with a blue "2"]

> [image: Bounty tab, showing without any active bounties, no blue "0" appears]

Comment: Whoa ... so many downvoters. Could someone add a single reason then why do you need this zero counter visible?

Comment: Maybe you could add a sentence or two why such a minor cosmetic detail, which most users will never be able to even see, should be changed instead of using the  development resources of SO for things the whole community will benefit from?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I think we need to stop talk as a SO dev team manager, or as a SO stock-owners. Do you really know how they choose the feature from MSE to do?

Comment: What you propose would be more consistent with most of the UI which SE uses. However, personally, I'd like that to display "0" when it's "0", as it's an extra confirmation that the system thinks there are no flags, rather than that there's a bug and no flag tasks are being shown (although, it could still be a bug). Admittedly, if I ever saw that indicator show 0 flags on SO Main, I'd probably take a screenshot to commemorate it.

Comment: @Makyen I didn't get clearly, do you want to see "0" on top bar next to diamond as well or only the "0" icon on flags tab inside the mod dashboard?

Comment: I'd like both, but that's largely because the top-bar flags indicator on SO is always present, so going there is part of my workflow. I find that getting to the mod pages is significantly easier when the # flags link in the topbar is visible. For SO, it's really only an issue on Meta SO, because SO main *always* has flags. I could use the link to the dashboard in the mod-inbox popup, but opening that popup still auto-marks everything as read, which is not something I want to have happen when I just want to go to the mod dashboard, or bounce from there to the "links" mod page, on MSO.

Answer (score 4):

To be honest questions about mod-tooling is probably better placed on the Moderators Team rather than MSE - particularly since this has no relevance for the vast majority of users *here* since they never see it.

But since it's here anyway.. I'd say leave it as-is. Contrary to being a distraction it's a comforting feeling to see 0 there, my eye will scan that far on the page and, if it sees zero there it goes no further. Removing that indicator then makes that harder.

Comment: Why do we can't look at this like "No indicator - no issues to handle"? Why add some bright spot at the page if there's no need to distract for?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ I'm not sure what answer you're looking for, my answer post explains why *for my workflow* I like having the indicator there and don't find it distracting. I'm not saying "I'm right and you're wrong" - if anything I doubt there **is** an objective "right" answer. It's all a matter of opinion and personal preference.

Comment: Of course there's a [relevant XKCD](https://xkcd.com/1172/)